# Grant rights on a certificate to an app through the shell

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, keychain, automation

I'm currently looking for a way to grant an application rights to a certificate in my /Library/Keychains/System.keychain through the shell.  I can currently do this through the Keychain Access App by clicking on the System Keychain, selecting the Keys category, double-clicking the "Imported Private Key" item, and then finally clicking on Access Control tab.  From here I can grant an application rights to access the private key.

Can I automate this via terminal command as I would like to use this in a bash script?

Comment: I haven't made a tool like that so I don't know if it will work or if you'll run into a design security barrier - but have you looked at the `security` binary and tried to read the keychain item in question?

Comment: Yes, I have been going through the security command, but there doesn't appear to be much related to setting ACLs on certificates in the man pages.  The authorize parameter seems to be the parameter most related, but I've been fooling with that for the last day and can't seem to connect it to certificate security.